# How to add a horizontal scrollbar in the header of the table?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify. I have createв the following layout:

[image]

Basically you have a card with three rows:

1. First row contains the number of items to display and the search bar.
2. Second row contains the table.
3. Third row contains the pagination.

Now when the screen is smaller or for example the user opens the DevTools, it shrinks the table and then the columns of the table break into separated rows. You get something like:

[image]

I'm trying to figure a way to add a horizontal bar for it not to happen. How can I make it work? Looking for solution I tried to add `style="overflow-x: auto"` in different locations but it didn't work.

My current code:

```
<div>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="py-0">
          <div class="d-flex justify-space-between align-center flex-wrap">
            <div class="d-flex align-center flex-wrap my-3" id="table-view-per-page">
              <div class="ml-1 inline">show</div>
              <v-select
                v-model="tableItemsPerPage"
                :items="itemsPerPageOptions"
                outlined
                single-line
                hide-details
                dense
                class="inline tiny-select inline"
              ></v-select>
              <div class="mr-1 inline">details</div>
            </div>
            <div id="table-view-search">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="tableSearchText"
                class="my-3 smooth-input mr-4"
                :class="[expendSearchBar ? 'flex-grow-1' : 'tiny-input']"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="search"
                filled
                rounded
                dense
                single-line
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      class="elevation-1"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :items-per-page="tableItemsPerPage"
      :footer-props="tableFooterSettings"
      :loading="tableLoading"
      hide-default-footer
    >
      <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ header }">
          <div v-if="filters.hasOwnProperty(header.value)">
            <v-select
              v-model="filters[header.value]"
              :items="getColumnDropdownList(header.value)"
              :label=header.text
              flat hide-details small clearable
              class="table-column-small-select"
              style="padding-bottom: 12px"
              @click.capture.stop
            />
          </div>
          <div v-else style="padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px">
            {{ header.text }}
          </div>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.number="{ item }">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" :href="item.url">{{item.number}}</a>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 mt-2" style="text-align: right;" id="table-view-records-info">
      {{ getRecordsString() }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 mt-2" style="text-align: left;" id="table-view-records-nav">
      <v-pagination
        v-model="tableCrurentPage"
        primary
        :length="pages"
        color="#45B7FC"
        style="float: left;"
      ></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not quite clear if the table layout actually break, or the table goes to mobile layout after some breakpoint. if it is the second, then this is expected behaviour, implemented to prevent actually breaking the layout on small viewports, and can't be disabled.

Comment: @IgorMoraru I mean, when I go in the web to the DevTools and try to expand the border of the DevTools, it shrinks the page and the table. So the headers break into separated lines and I want it add a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @vesli please open the official [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) page, shrink the browser window width below ~400px and see what happens to the first table on that page. It is the same behaviour as in your case?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using
`"width: "600px";` or any fixed width in header. By this you can force your table to be in a fixed size and the scrollbar will appear for sure.